# Unable to retrieve a record from db using LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to retrieve a record for an update using below

```
var product= _db.Products.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
if (product!= null)
{
    product.StatusId = statusId;
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Product Model

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int TypeId { get; set; }
public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
public int? StatusId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public ProductStatus Status { get; set; }
public ICollection<ProductStatus> ProductStatuses { get; set; }
```

But, while retrieving the record in the first line, it throws an exception saying `{"Invalid column name 'ProductStatus_Id'."}`
I do have a ProductStatus table but not sure if it has anything to do with it

Comment: Is the error correct? What does your `Product.StatusId` model look like?

Comment: Yes thats the correct error and statusId is a foreign key in Product table to ProductStatus table

Comment: OK, but what does it look like in the model? What attributes are on it?

Comment: Do you mean the productstatus table or product?

Comment: The model - the class where you (or EF) have declared `Product`.

Comment: Added in the edited question

Comment: Isn't there supposed to be a `[Key]` attribute on that `Id` property?

Comment: I believe EF automatically recognizes it by its name (Id)

Comment: Could be that EF is confused by `StatusId` ending with `Id` too?

Comment: Is ICollection<ProductStatus> a part of your model or are you using it to populate a drop down list? If the latter, you should add [NotMapped] so EF doesn't setup a relationship.

Comment: Renaming id to Id has fixed the issue. Seems like a bug to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model doesn't specify a foreign key to the `ProductStatus` table, so it is trying to use EF's default convention, which is to look for a field called "ProductStatus_Id".

You can fix it by either adding a column called `ProductStatus_Id` to the `Products` table (and make it a FK to `ProductStatus`), or you can use a data annotation to specify a name (and also have a matching column).

Or, if you don't need `Product.ProductStatus`, remove the property from `Product` (which you could do temporarily to test.

Edit:
This page (first google hit for "ef foreign key", no affiliation) has some examples http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx